# Template return type of a function that needs to be virtual

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

Because the following is illegal:

```
struct A {
    template <typename T>
    virtual T* foo() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    template <typename T>
    virtual T* foo() override {return new T;}  // Simple example here.
};

template <typename T>
T* bar (A* a) {
    return a->foo<T>();  // The need for the virtual method.
}
```

and the template only appears in the return type, I've thought of a (naïve?) workaround using overload:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base { virtual void show() const = 0; };
struct Object : Base { virtual void show() const override {std::cout << "I am an Object.\n";} };
struct Thing : Base { virtual void show() const override {std::cout << "I am a Thing.\n";} };
struct Blob : Base { virtual void show() const override {std::cout << "I am a Blob.\n";} };

struct A {
    virtual Object* foo (Object&&) = 0;
    virtual Thing* foo (Thing&&) = 0;
    virtual Blob* foo (Blob&&) = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    virtual Object* foo (Object&&) override {return fooHelper<Object>();}
    virtual Thing* foo (Thing&&) override {return fooHelper<Thing>();}
    virtual Blob* foo (Blob&&) override {return fooHelper<Blob>();}
private:
    template <typename T>
    T* fooHelper() {return new T;}  // Simple example here.
};

template <typename T>
T* bar (A* a) {
    return a->foo(T{});
}

int main() {
    B* b = new B;
    Base* list[] = {bar<Object>(b), bar<Thing>(b), bar<Blob>(b)};
    for (const Base* x : list) x->show();
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it is only feasible if there are not too many types for `T`.  But what if there are?  Furthermore, there is now the maintenance problem when new types for `T` are introduced later.

Can someone think of a better solution than this?  The known visitor pattern as a virtual template workaround does not apply here (I don't think) because the template does not appear in the argument.

Comment: DO you need covariant return type?

Comment: @marom  My `T* create (A* a)` function is my goal.  I used covariant return types only as a solution, but is not the goal itself.  If there is another way without covariant return types, it would be nice to see.

Comment: You have so many memory leaks in your example.

Comment: Do you need your function argument (`a`) to be part of a class hierarchy at all? Otherwise it's type could just be another template argument.

Comment: What is your goal? To keep `A` as simple as possible, like only returning `Base` and have maybe one `foo` function? How many subclasses of `A` are there and do they all have to support all types subclassed from `Base`? Is compile time type safety and enforcement of the interface of `A` absolutely necessary for you or would you be willing to make compromises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
    T* fooHelper() {return new T;}
};

template <typename T>
T* create (A* a) {
    return a->foo(T{});
}
```

The instance of A has no effect on the T you return. I'm assuming maybe that's supposed to be an argument.  It also seems like you want a factory. How about using a member function:

```
template < typename T, typename FactoryType, 
           typename MemFnType, typename ArgType >
T* create(FactoryType* f, MemFnType mfn, ArgType a)
{
    return (f->*mfn)(a);
}
```

Full Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base { virtual void show() const = 0; };
struct Object : Base { virtual void show() const override {std::cout << "I am an Object.\n";} };
struct Thing : Base { virtual void show() const override {std::cout << "I am a Thing.\n";} };
struct Blob : Base { virtual void show() const override {std::cout << "I am a Blob.\n";} };

struct Args
{
    int someArg;
};

struct Factory
{
    // normally 'a' would be passed to the Object constructor.
    // omitted to save edits.
    Object* asObject(const Args& a) { return new Object(); }
    Thing* asThing(const Args& a) { return new Thing(); }
    Blob* asBlob(const Args& a) { return new Blob(); }
};

template < typename T, typename FactoryType, 
           typename MemFnType, typename ArgType >
T* create(FactoryType& f, MemFnType mfn, ArgType& a)
{
    return (&f->*mfn)(a);
}

int main() {
    Args arg;
    Factory f;
    Base* list[] = {create<Object>(f, &Factory::asObject, arg), create<Thing>(f, &Factory::asThing, arg), create<Blob>(f, &Factory::asBlob, arg)};
    for (const Base* x : list) x->show();
}
```

Adding constructible types just requires adding the type itself and the related  factory function.  You can even generalize it to a full template argument list instead of a single argument type.

Comment: It's not a factory function I'm after.  I just named the function `create` randomly, and the body of the function I just made up here to show that `T`,`a`, and `foo` are needed, but a `T*` is returned (but not a factory function).  I appreciate you trying to help though.  But I'm seeking an improvement of my solution without any redesign.

Comment: So what you are saying is that `B` contains pointers to `Thing`, `Blob` etc. or has other means to look them up, but does not always recreate them?

Comment: @ mat69  `B::fooHelper()` returns a T* but does not necessarily create one.  `C::fooHelper()` returns a T* in a different way, etc...

Comment: @prestokeys so one of the purposes (or rather the purpose?) of subclasses of `A` is to provide different means to retrieve objects which subclass `Base`? Does that mean that any subclass of `A` has a `fooHelper` with the same interface, but different contents?

Comment: @ mat69  Yes, you are right.  Though, I'm not really after the factory pattern here, I will try a redesign similar to your solution, creating a new class to manage what I'm trying to manage, and use templates with that instead.